# Why my each word reversing code is not reversing some words?

Tags: python, stack

#### What I want to do

I am trying to make a program that reverses each words, but not reverses words in tags.
Example input and output:

Input:

```
Thank you stack overflow
```

Output:

```
knahT uoy kcats wolfrevo
```

**If the word is in tags, it should be not reversed.** Like this:

Input:

```
<tag>something
```

Ouput:

```
<tag>gnihtemos
```

#### My code

I tried to solve this using stack algorithm.

```
s = input()
def stackprint(st):
    while st != []:
        print(st.pop(), end="")
stack = []
tag = False
for ch in s:
    if ch == '<':
        stackprint(stack)
        tag = True
        print(ch, end="")
    elif ch == '>':
        tag = False
        print(ch, end="")
    elif tag:
        print(ch, end="")
    else:
        if ch == ' ':
            stackprint(stack)
            print(ch, end="")
        else:
            stack.append(ch)
print("".join(stack))
```

#### The problem

But, my code is not working if there is only one word or there is no tag. When there is no tag, the last word is not reversed, and when there is only one word, it doesn't get reversed.

The output now:

**First**

When Input:

```
<tag>something
```

Ouput:

```
<tag>something
```

^ I need something to be reversed.

**Second**

Input:

```
Thank you stack overflow
```

Ouput:

```
knahT uoy kcats overflow
```

^ I need overflow to be reversed.

### Important

I need whatever inside < > should be not reversed. **If the word is in tags, it should be not reversed**
like input:

```
<tag>word<tag>
```

output:

```
<tag>drow<tag>
```

There will be no space between a tag and a word.

```
Thank you <tag>stack overflow
```

```
knahT uoy <tag>kcats wolfrevo
```

Comment: Instead of joining the stack at the end, call `stackprint` method. It will ensure that the stack is emptied before the script exits.

Comment: Now seems like an excellent time to learn to debug. Work out on paper how you want your code to flow and which values you expect your variables to have at which point in the code. How does this compare to the values you're actually getting?

Comment: @NotThatGuy What do you mean?

Comment: is there going to be a space between "<tag>" and the next word? what would be the output for this "Thank you <tag>stack overflow"?

Comment: Did you test your code again after editing it? If not, you should do that and it's usually not recommended to make edits to questions that could potentially fix the problem you were having and thus invalidate the question (but rather leave that information for the answers, or just delete the question if you feel it's unlikely to be helpful to others). Also, you probably meant `stackprint(stack)` and not `stackprint(st)`.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Oh, yes. Sorry. I was editing in a hurry

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri No, no space between

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri `knahT uoy <tag>kcats wolfrevo`

Comment: Case in point: [your code now appears to give the correct output](https://ideone.com/Ru2qVW).

Comment: @Yogaraj That did the trick! Add an answer please. I'll be happy to accept it

Comment: @Yogaraj Please add that comment into an answer. It worked with that solution. I'll be happy to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comment section, instead of printing the stack with the join method, calling the stackprint method to ensure that the stack is emptied will give you the desired result.

```
s = input()
def stackprint(st):
    while st != []:
        print(st.pop(), end="")
stack = []
tag = False
for ch in s:
    if ch == '<':
        stackprint(stack)
        tag = True
        print(ch, end="")
    elif ch == '>':
        tag = False
        print(ch, end="")
    elif tag:
        print(ch, end="")
    else:
        if ch == ' ':
            stackprint(stack)
            print(ch, end="")
        else:
            stack.append(ch)
stackprint(stack)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work with the examples you have provided:

```
def revSetence(sentence):
    sentence = sentence + " ";
    flag = False
    final_sentence = ""
    word = ""
    for letter in sentence:
        if letter == "<":
            flag = True
        if letter == ">":
            flag = False
        if letter.isalpha():
            if flag:
                final_sentence = final_sentence + letter
            else:
                word = word + letter
        else:
            if len(word) > 0:
                final_sentence = final_sentence + word[::-1] 
            final_sentence = final_sentence + letter
            word =""
    return final_sentence
```